# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/component/UIViewAction on TomEE startup

Tags: maven, jsf, apache-tomee, omnifaces, tomee-7

I'm trying to migrate a web project (all JARs in `WEB-INF/lib`) to a maven web project (all JARs in `pom.xml`).

This project uses following libraries:

- JSF 2.2
- PrimeFaces
- BootsFaces
- OmniFaces

It runs on TomEE.

The following error appears on TomEE startup:

> NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/component/UIViewAction

But JSF2 library is provided by TomEE on classpath.

Here is my `pom.xml`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.lb</groupId>
<artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>XXX</name>
<description>Application XXX</description>

<url>http://XXX.fr</url>
<organization>
    <name>XXX</name>
    <url>http://XXX.fr</url>
</organization>
<inceptionYear>2016</inceptionYear>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <javase.version>1.7</javase.version>
    <javaee.version>7.0</javaee.version>
</properties>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>XXX</id>
        <name>YYY</name>
        <email>ZZZ@gmail.com</email>
    </developer>
</developers>

<build>
    <directory>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</directory>
    <finalName>XXX</finalName>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.java</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${javase.version}</source>
                <target>${javase.version}</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/resources</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <packagingExcludes>
                    **/*.java,
                </packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bootsfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootsfaces</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class [`javax/faces/component/UIViewAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewAction.html) is new since JSF 2.2. You're thus not using JSF 2.2 at all. You're most likely using only TomEE 1.x, which ships with JSF 2.1.

This problem is triggered by OmniFaces 2.2. It requires JSF 2.2.

You have 2 options:

1. Downgrade to OmniFaces 2.1. Even though OmniFaces 2.x officially [requires](http://omnifaces.org) JSF 2.2, OmniFaces versions 2.0 and 2.1 do not have deploy time JSF 2.2 dependencies. OmniFaces version 2.2 was with `<o:viewAction>` tag the first version to require JSF 2.2 during deploy time.
2. Upgrade to TomEE 7.x, the first version to implement Java EE 7 and thus inherently JSF 2.2. It's currently only [available](http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html) as M1 release. Final release is expected within months.

Comment: 2nd option works quite well. I'm using `TomEE 7.0.0-M1` in two projects to have JSF 2.2+ and it's working as expected. Should be valid solution for @ludovic Bernada

Comment: Hello, 2nd option works well for me too. I should have ask before spending 2 hours searching :) Thanks BalusC for your answer and  MWiesner for the test.