# PrimeFaces LazyDataModel#load() method not invoked anymore after adding OmniFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces, lazydatamodel

PrimeFaces `LazyDataModel` worked before adding OmniFaces jar into pom.xml.
It invokes `load()` method of `LazyDataModel`.

LazyPostDataModel.java

```
public class LazyPostDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Post> {
    private PostService postService;
    private PostCriteria postCriteria;

    public LazyPostDataModel(PostService postService, PostCriteria postCriteria) {
        this.postCriteria = postCriteria;
        this.postService = postService;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Post> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
        //other process
    }
}
```

I just add the following dependency into pom.xml for OmniFaces. It does not invoke `load()` method .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

post.xhtml

```
<h:form id="postTableForm">
    <p:inputText value="#{ManagePostActionBean.postCriteria.name}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{ManagePostActionBean.search}" update="postTable"/>
    <p:outputPanel id="listPanel">
        <p:dataTable var="post" value="#{ManagePostActionBean.postDataModel}" id="postTable"
            paginator="true" style="width:100%;" lazy="true"
            rows="10"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100" rowIndexVar="index">
            <p:column headerText="No" style="width:50px;">
                <h:outputText value="#{index + 1}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{post.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Description">
                <h:outputText value="#{post.description}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

ManagePostActionBean.java

```
@Named(value = "ManagePostActionBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ManagePostActionBean {
    @Inject
    private PostService postService;
    private LazyDataModel<Post> postDataModel;
    private PostCriteria postCriteria;

    public void onLoad() {
        System.out.println("ManagePostActionBean Init....");
        postCriteria = new PostCriteria();
        postDataModel = new LazyPostDataModel(postService, postCriteria);
    }

    public LazyDataModel<Post> getPostDataModel() {
        return postDataModel;
    }

    public PostCriteria getPostCriteria() {
        return postCriteria;
    }

    public void setPostCriteria(PostCriteria postCriteria) {
        this.postCriteria = postCriteria;
    }

    public void search() {
        resetPagination();
        postDataModel = new LazyPostDataModel(postService, postCriteria);
    }
}
```

my environment is

```
JSF 2.2
Primefaces 5.0
JDK 1.7
apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.3 (TomEE)
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mutu</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories> 
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8-02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8-02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>green-cool</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>  
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>  
            <version>2.4.1</version>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you manually upgrade JSF from 2.1 to 2.2 in TomEE? If so, how exactly? TomEE 1.x is by default not JSF 2.2 but JSF 2.1 and then you should use OmniFaces 1.x instead of 2.x, or migrate server to TomEE 7.x.

Comment: @BalusC I just add com.sun.face 2.2 in pom.xml manually. it is not OK?

Comment: No ... `provided` means "Target runtime (the appserver) already provides it". Moreover, TomEE 1.x provides Apache MyFaces (org.apache.myfaces), not Oracle Mojarra (com.sun.faces). I'm only surprised that you didn't see an exception during deploy as in this closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35226794

Comment: And you say you use PF 5.3 but the pom show 5.0... Please correct all...

Comment: @BalusC I need to upgrade JSF 2.2 on Tomee? If so, I will googling for that. After that, I will feed back u later

Comment: I posted an answer. In all honesty, I have to say that it's kind of strange to see someone using Spring on a Java EE server. I can understand why one would use Spring on a barebones Tomcat servletcontainer (as you can't install EJB on it), but TomEE already ships EJB/JTA/JPA/CDI/JAX-RS/etc out the box so there's no real need for Spring. By the way, your JSTL dependency must be marked `provided`.

Comment: @BalusC, thank for your help. Actually I am thinking to choose the way.
JSF 2.2 + Spring + Tomcat 7. But I get   '@PostConstruct calling multiple time in ViewScope bean` error. Some reference suggest to use CDI for that case. That's why I choose this way(as my post). I will choose option 1 or 2 of your answer. But, I need to test both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using TomEE 1.x, which ships with JSF 2.1 (Apache MyFaces).

OmniFaces 2.2 [requires](http://omnifaces.org/#download) JSF 2.2.

You have 2 options:

1. Downgrade to OmniFaces 2.1. Even though OmniFaces 2.x officially requires JSF 2.2, OmniFaces versions 2.0 and 2.1 do not have deploy time JSF 2.2 dependencies. OmniFaces version 2.2 was with `<o:viewAction>` tag the first version to require JSF 2.2 during deploy time.
2. Upgrade to TomEE 7.x, the first version to implement Java EE 7 and thus inherently JSF 2.2. It's currently only [available](http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html) as M1 release. Final release is expected within months.